# Laravel failure to pass tabindex variable between partials

Tags: include, laravel, laravel-3, partials

I've run into a slight problem with my enumerated tab indices using Laravel.

I have a simple controller

```
public function get_login()
{
    return View::make('auth.login')->with('i', 1);
}
```

Then in my view I'm loading two partials.

```
@layout('layout.master')
@section('content')
    <article>
        @include('layout.partials.login-form')
    </article>
    <aside>
        @include('layout.partials.sidebar-guest')
    </aside>
@endsection
```

The partials both have forms and are collecting the $i variable and using it like this

```
{{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('tabindex' => $i++)) }}
```

The issue is that whilst the $i variable increments fine within the partial, after the @include is completed and the next @include is loaded it does not see that the $i variable has incremented.

Is there any easy way around this?

Comment: Works like a charm in L3 & even in L4. Try to do simple testing in new view & related included subview

Comment: It works fine for me it I just have one include. Eg if the form is loaded directly in the <article> and then I include my partial for the sidebar. But when I run an @include on both partials both of them have $i as 1. Meaning I end up with duplicate tabindices. I think it's probably reasonable enough - perhaps I need to handle tabindex counting via sessions or something?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have two option:

1) Send the $i variable from the controller:

```
public function get_login()
{
    $i=1;
    return view('auth.login')->with('i');
}
```

And then you use $i variable in the view

```
{{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('tabindex' => $i++)) }}
```

2) Define the $i variable in the view and use it:

Controler:

```
public function get_login()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

View:

```
@layout('layout.master')
@section('content')
@php
    $i = 1;
@endphp
    <article>
        @include('layout.partials.login-form')
    </article>
    <aside>
        @include('layout.partials.sidebar-guest')
    </aside>
@endsection
```

Then you use it in each of parts of the view:

```
{{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('tabindex' => $i++)) }}
```

Good luck.